# curl and nodeJS `request` library do not produce same resutls

Tags: javascript, curl, https, request, httpresponse

When I run `curl https://purduesports.com/` I get the site's HTML code. This works as intended/expected.

But when I run the following in a JavaScript file, I get a response body that is empty. Here is the code, and below is the response:

```
var request = require('request');
return request('https://purduesports.com/', function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error); 
    console.log('statusCode:', JSON.stringify(response)); 
    console.log('body:', body); 
    return body;

});
```

```
error: null
statusCode: {"statusCode":200,"body":"","headers":{"server":"Microsoft-IIS/10.0","date":"Wed, 01 Jan 2020 20:11:07 GMT","connection":"close","content-length":"0"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"https:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"purduesports.com","port":443,"hostname":"purduesports.com","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/sports/baseball/roster","path":"/sports/baseball/roster","href":"https://purduesports.com/sports/baseball/roster"},"method":"GET","headers":{}}}
body:
```

As you can see, the body is `""` but the response code is `200`. This doesn't make sense to me because when I run this same code with, for example, https://google.com/,  I get the HTML code in the body. My hunch is that the HTML code is too large to return in the body, but I do not know.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Presuming you have permission to scrape the site.. I guess in your curl request your setting user agent? Do the same with requests. https://runkit.com/lcherone/5e0cff9821cdfa001aed6091

Comment: That worked! Why did i need to set the user agent??

Comment: some sites dont like scraping, for good reason.. so they add futile layers to prevent it, this one is just checking for user agent.. expect rate limits, IDS and ip bans.. unless you have permission of course

Comment: Very appreciative of the help and guidance!!